# When I do this UV unwrap the cube becomes transparent and shows vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: uv, transparency

When I UV unwrap the cube, and place a logo/image in it I get 2 things:
1) the Cube becomes transparent. How can I keep the diffuse not transparent. I used the transparent node to get the alpha from the logo.

2) I also get some weird vertical and horizontal lines.

Any ideas?

Is this the way to do this? Is there a better way? any links to tutorials?

Here is the blend file:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines are most likely a problem with the image Alpha channel. However, the Blend file you uploaded does not include the image - you need to select 'Pack' in the UV editor to pack the image into the file before you upload it. However, load the image into an image editor and check the Alpha channel to ensure there are no lines or other noise present. Also, set the Image Texture node to 'Clip' rather than 'Repeat' - this way the other 5 UV faces (outside the UV boundary in your image) definitely won't be picking up any content from the image.

As for the cube becoming transparent, you do realise that you're using a *Transparent* shader for the red shading...? Replace the Transparent shader node with a Diffuse shader node and it will no longer be transparent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Rich, it worked perfectly. The lines, where because in the mix shader I had the diffuse on bottom, and it need to be on top, and the transparent on bottom, what made it work.